# App Store Connect Xcode Apk. was generate from ionic 4

Tags: xcode, ionic4

Problem in Validate App, using Xcode 10.2.1

Project Format: I tried all formats. (Xcode 9.3-compatible, ...)

I receveid that message:
Invalid Toolchain. Your app was built with an unsupported version of Xcode or SDK. If you plan to submit this build to the App Store, make sure you are using the GM version of Xcode 9 and the SDK for iOS 11, tvOS 11, watchOS 4, or macOS 10.13 or later. If you are using an Xcode beta version to test your app, make sure you are using the latest supported version. For more information about supported beta versions, view the TestFlight Release Notes (https://developer.apple.com/testflight/release-notes/).

I last option is trying to install Xcode 9.